# page header style

Tags: xetex, fancyhdr

I'm wondering how to achieve this header style using two rules with a thick one on the bottom, and the page number in a shadowed square ?.

The version in the image below is the right page version.
[image: page header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather crude (but sufficient) way of constructing the shadowed boxes. `\headrulewidth` specified the wider/thicker rule while `\hrulefill` sets a thinner/regular rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}% Adjust based on content
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}% Thick header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule (default)
\fancyhead[LO]{Some header text \hrulefill\hspace*{4em}}%
\fancyhead[RO]{
  \raisebox{\depth}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[4em]{\phantom{\thepage}}}\hspace*{2pt}}}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{5pt}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\makebox[4em]{\thepage}}}}%
}
\fancyhead[RE]{\hspace*{4em}\hrulefill Some header text}%
\fancyhead[LE]{
  \raisebox{\depth}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[4em]{\phantom{\thepage}}}}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{2pt}\raisebox{5pt}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\makebox[4em]{\thepage}}}}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```